# Expand/Collapse animation in Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I'm trying to have my listview expanded/collapsed with an animation, and I have the following code.
What I wanna have is a listview, on the top part of the screen, that expands and collapses, but when it collapses up, I just wanna see the currently selected item from the listview (one one item, one row).

```
public static Animation expand(final View v, final boolean expand) {
        try {
            Method m = v.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("onMeasure", int.class,
                    int.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(v,
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            ((View) v.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth(),
                            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (expand) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 50;
        } else {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight;
        }
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                    Transformation t) {
                int newHeight = 50;
                if (expand) {
                    newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                } else {
                    newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
                }
                v.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
                v.requestLayout();
                if (interpolatedTime == 1 && !expand)
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        a.setDuration(500);
        return a;
    }
```

The problem is that when collapsing, I'd like to have the first row of the listview visible, and not the listview completely hidden, but I can't find the part of the code that will do that.
Any help, please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking for here. Could you try to be a bit more clear?

Comment: I'm asking if somebody can take a look at the code and tell me why my listview is completely collapsed when doing the animation, even if commenting the lines `if (interpolatedTime == 1 && !expand)v.setVisibility(View.GONE);` it is still hidden, and there's no `height = 0`parameter anywhere

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say is, could you be more clear on the effect you are trying to create?

Comment: @spierce7 I improved the description adding some more text, thanks